# One uiview stop working when interacting with another

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

On the same UIViewController, there's one UILabel being updated every 0.01s by a NSTimer. In the same Controller, there's an UIView containing a TableController from another .nib.

When I scroll the table, the UILabel stops from updating till the scroll finishes. Any ideas for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your timer with "NSRunLoopCommonModes" or "UITrackingRunLoopMode" mode.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

- (void)timer
{
    label.text = @"different text";
}
```

And read [NSRunLoop Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/addTimer%3aforMode%3a), [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) and [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)

Comment: This is a perfect answer. The solution worked like a charm, and the sources explained and helped me understanding why.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

put the label updation code in a Thread.. it should solve your problem.

Comment: did you try this approach before?

Comment: NO. I have applied concepts. Since threads are independent, so it should not affect its method..